# Torque acting on car trailers

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, vectors, torque, moment

My question: "Which car trailer below will be moved in a straight forward line?"

*Relevant info*: All forces (represented by the arrows) in the diagram are **equal in magnitude**. The car trailer diagrams below seem to me very similar in terms of the net torque that acts on each of them. The net torque must be 0 in both, doesnt it? However, according to the answers, **only** trailer 2 is the one to travel in a straight forward line. Did they make a mistake or am I the one to overlook something?

**Note:** I received the questions exactly as I present them here from the organization I got them from. Therefore, I suffer from not being able to provide more context and specifications. I am only being able to provide my assumptions based on my preliminary knowledge.

[Please don't pay attention to the size of the wheels]

Wondering about your valuable opinions

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drawing is not particularly accurate. For instance, although it does not affect the answer, $0.25$m and $0.5$m on the second drawing have about the same length.

Apart from that (without going into the details of the hook-up), it appears that the idea here is that the forces acting on trailer $1$ appear to be symmetric, but the link to the trailer is not in the middle - it is shifted to the left.

The forces acting on trailer $2$ appear to be asymmetric, but, in fact, they are, since the torque from $F_4$ is balanced out by the torque from $F_5$ and $F_6$ and the trailer is hooked up in the middle.

So, it looks more like a trick question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. I had some trouble with the app I am drawing my pictures with; I just downloaded a more accurate one, where I can zoom in; see edit for the accurate picture. It am sure it will make a huge difference..

Comment: @Englishterian On the updated diagram, trailer $1$ has a symmetric hook-up, so it should move straight as well.